# Are there motivating examples for graphs with negative edge weights?

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

Every example I come up with for a directed graph with negative edge weights seems contrived in some way.

Can anyone name some real ones? Even better if they aren't obviously networks to start with.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624468/negative-edge-in-graph.

Comment: How about if vertices represent street intersections, directed edges represent bicycle routes between two intersections, and the edge weight is the amount of effort needed to get from A to B? Uphill routes have a positive weight, uphill routes on steep hills have a large positive weight, and steep downhill routes have a negative weight because not only do you not have to pedal, but you can use the acquired momentum to help reduce the effort required to get up the next hill.

Comment: That's kind of what I mean by contrived! There's no way you'd actually use that to plan a route. In Paris the bike-hire scheme will actually pay you to cycle uphill, but even so, there are lots of other considerations to take into account.